# Delphi's GetTableNames sometimes returns tables with owner names, and sometimes not

Tags: delphi

I have some apps that connect to ODBC databases using ADO, and BDE. I have to call GetTableNames to return a list of table. Sometimes, I find that the table names are qualified with owner names, and sometimes not. The permutations are mysterious to me. Anyone can shed light on this?

Comment: In both ado and bde? against which database?

Comment: Possibly because the table names are keywords? Can you give some examples of table names when they are qualified?

Comment: Is it a mix between both in the same call or is it always one way or the other on a given call to the database?

Comment: Are you always logged in as the same user?

Answer (score 0):

Most DBMS these days provide a way to retreive a list of tablenames in a result set. I would suggest this approach rather than using the built in GetTableNames function.

For example, on MySQL it is

```
SHOW TABLES
```

on MS SQL Server it is:

```
SELECT name FROM <database name>..sysobjects where xtype = 'U';
```

Hope that helps